# Is there a way to get IE to display the black star character (HTML entity &starf; or raw ★)?

Tags: html, encoding, fonts

Is there a way to get Windows XP to display the black star character (HTML entity `&starf;` or raw ★)?

When I test in on windows using HTML doctype and UTF-8, `&starf;` shows as literally as `&starf;` while ★ shows as a square.

Comment: It was to prevent markdown from rendering.

Comment: You can use `\`` (backticks) to render as the underlying code. `:)`

Comment: @JarredFarrish: You can use \ to backtick the backticks: `\`` `:)`

Comment: I'm not sure `&starf;` is defined for all browser versions. Which IE version are you using? Have you tried `&#9733;`, specifying the unicode code-point directly? Seems to work in Chrome: &#9733;

Comment: `&#9733;` works on my my mac in any browser I try.  I'm beginning to think it's an issue specific to Windows XP as it is broken in both Chrome and IE8 on a clean test image.

Comment: @Joey - `&starf;` is defined as a [named character reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/named-character-references.html#named-character-references) in HTML5.

Comment: Ouch. And I thought that madness had an end with Unicode being now the predominant encoding on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Use the character as such, in UTF-8 encoded data, or the numeric character reference `&#x2605;` or `&#9733;`. Do not use the `&starf;` entity, which is a [proposed HTML5 entity](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#named-character-references) with very limited browser support (last spring when I tested, *no* browser supported them; now some do).

The reason why your attempt with the character as such fails is most probably a font issue. It depends on the fonts available on the user’s system, on the browser, and on the CSS settings on the page. To maximize the odds, use a `font-family` declaration that contains fonts known to have a glyph for the character. For more info check my page on [special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

[Font support to the BLACK STAR character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/fontsupport.htm) is relatively limited, and there is no guarantee that all computers have a font supporting it. But you could wrap the character in a `span` element and set e.g.

```
font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Quivira, Symbola, Code2000, STIX,
  "Linux Libertine", MingLiU, "DFKai-SB";
```

on that element.