# Why some browser can not display ★ star sign?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, utf-8

Why some browser can not display ★ star sign ?

I test my code on chrome, ie8 but this browser cannot dispaly ★ star sign.

And on header i put this code

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

how can i do that ?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353043/is-there-a-way-to-get-ie-to-display-the-black-star-character-html-entity-starf) try this albert

Comment: user3801433 , but in firefox it's display ok

Answer (score 0):

specifying the charset doesn't always it is always set. Use your developer tool to ensure that the page is encoded using utf-8. Also, try to use the ascii code for the star to see if it would work `&#9733;`

Comment: The browser knows how to handle it. Just replace the star with the code. You can put it within any tag or in the middle of a paragraph. It doesn't matter really.

Comment: Aman could you polease give me some demo about how to place `&#9733;`

Comment: Sure, feel free to experiment in this page:
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VTl31tAhDA

Comment: OK, i try, but in chrome not display too

Comment: @albertnertuwe It looks like a font issue